# Homomorphism induced by group action

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions, group-homomorphism

If $G$ is a group acting on $X$, which is a set of all left cosets of $H\leq G$ (such that $|G:H|=k$), by left multiplication, then this group action induces a homomorphism $\phi: G\to S_X$, such that $\phi(g)=\pi_g$, where $\pi_g(aH)=gaH$.

I would like to analyze this homomorphism, and I would appreciate your involvement (and help). It is in my understanding that this homomorphism is injective because $\ker(\phi)=e$. But I've also been trying to understand if it's surjective. Take an arbitrary permutation $\pi_{g'}$, then $\phi(g')=\pi_{g'}$, which implies that $\exists g\in G$ for each $\pi_g\in S_n$, and this $g$ is unique. We can also find an inverse homomorphism $\psi:S_X\to G$ defined by $\psi(\pi_g)=g$. Does this mean that the homomorphism $\phi$ is in fact an isomorphism, and that $|G|$ must be equal $|S_X|$?

Comment: what is $S_X$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of $\phi$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_{|G/H|}$, but that's all you can say about it; any transitive subgroup can appear (exercise). The kernel of $\phi$ is the intersection $\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$ of all of the conjugates of $H$ (exercise).

Comment: You're right about subsets, I've corrected that part. Can you please let me know what is a transitive subgroup?

Comment: @sequence: a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ is a subgroup which acts transitively on $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$.

Comment: The intersection $\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$ is the kernel of $\phi$, you mean?

Comment: @sequence: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: But $\phi$ operates on elements of $G$, not on sets?

Comment: @sequence: yes, that's right. What is the question?

Comment: If $\ker(\phi)= \bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$, then $\phi(ghg^{-1})=\pi_{ghg^{-1}}$. Does $\pi_{ghg^{-1}}$ have to be equal to $\pi_e$?

Comment: @sequence: you've misunderstood me. I'm taking the intersection, not the union. The kernel consists of elements which can be written in the form $ghg^{-1}, h \in H$ for *every* $g \in G$.

Comment: Yes, but will an element of this intersection not have the form of $ghg^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$?

Comment: @sequence: that's correct, but it doesn't follow that every element of this form lies in the kernel. Here is a more specific form of the exercise: show that $gHg^{-1}$ is the stabilizer of the coset $gH$.

Comment: But only those that commute with all elements in $G$, i.e. $h\in Z(G)$? Which would imply that $Z(G)\leq H$?

Comment: @sequence: no, the center is irrelevant here.

Comment: OK I think I got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But how did you come up with the idea that $gHg^{-1}$ is the stabilizer of $gH$? I mean that it is clear now, but what made you come up with just this idea? Did you just see it immediately?

Comment: @sequence: it's not hard to see this. What does it mean for an element $g' \in G$ to stabilize $gH$? It means that $g' g H = g H$. This means that $g^{-1} g' g H = H$, which is equivalent to saying that $g^{-1} g' g \in H$.

Comment: If $g^{-1}g'g \in H$ does it mean that $gHg^{-1}\subset H$?

Comment: @sequence: no. It means $g^{-1} g' g = h$ for some $h \in H$, hence $g' = g h g^{-1}$, which is what I was trying to show.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan: After your explanation I understand what the kernel of $\phi$ is. However, I'm wondering about the following: $\pi_{ghg^{-1}}(aH)=ghg^{-1}aH = H$, since $ghg^{-1} \in aHa^{-1}\implies ghg^{-1}a\in aH$. Where is my error?After your explanation I understand what the kernel of $\phi$ is. However, I'm wondering about the following: $\pi_{ghg^{-1}}(aH)=ghg^{-1}aH = H$, since $ghg^{-1} \in aHa^{-1}\implies ghg^{-1}a\in aH$. Where is my error?

Comment: @sequence: I don't understand your question. Also, why do you introduce two notations for the action of $g$? You don't need both $\phi(g)$ and $\pi_g$.

Comment: If we take an element $ghg^{-1}\in \ker\phi$ then $\phi(ghg^{-1})=\pi_{ghg^{-1}}$.  Now $\pi_{ghg^{-1}}(aH)=ghg^{-1}aH=aH$ (since $ghg^{-1}a \in aH$). Nevermind, I see where I wasn't right.

Comment: @sequence: if $ghg^{-1}$ is assumed to lie in the kernel of $\phi$ then we have $\pi_{ghg^{-1}}(aH) = aH$, by definition. So I still don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

For arbitrary subgroup $H$ of $G$, the homomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow S_X=S_{G/H}$ is not necessarily injective or surjective.

Consider $G$ with $|G|=9$ and $|H|=3$. We will get a homomorphism 
$\phi\colon G \rightarrow S_{G/H}\cong S_3$. Comparing orders, you will see that it is neither injective nor surjective.